# how to create query in sql query builder visual studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

[image]

how to Use the grid pane to add a calculated column that multiplies the UnitPrice column by the OnHand column, and assign an alias of Total to this column. Then, accept this change to return to the Configure Data Source dialog box.

Comment: Why don't you enter it directly into the SQL pane, `, UnitPrice * OnHand AS Total` and hit `Execute Query`. If it's what you want, then click `OK` to make the change. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Although I advise learning the SQL language, and writing the SQL statements by hand.

You can type the expression within the "column" column. Like: UnitPrice * OnHand

You enter the Total into the "Alias" column.